# How do I get the location correctly from OSM database?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, openstreetmap

i have managed to download the database from OSM using Nominatim and import that database to Sqlserver Management Studio. When i write the query to access a table that contain (Id, Location, latitude, longitude), it returns me garbage location. i don't understand that how can i get the location correct against the latitude and longitude. Below I post a screenshot of the problem that i am facing. Someone guide me[image]

Comment: Coordinate located at US country.. nothing specific

Comment: I did not understand. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: is your location is a blob datatype?

Comment: my location's datatype is 'geography'.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: I am using 'Sql server management studio'.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a SQL query that can retrieve the data for you:

https://github.com/francesco1119/OSM_to_MSSQL

without using Nominatim  but directly retrieving JSON to SSMS on the fly.

Just add the "location" between the fields that `OPENJSON` needs to parse